# Yii2 can't save user data from the form

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to implement user profiles in Yii2 (advanced template). I've used Gii CRUD generator for the User model and renamed everywhere "view" to "profile" (in controller, views etc.). But when I try to save updated data, it is not saved in database while `$model->save()` is returning `true`.

**Model:**

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%user}}';
}


public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
}


public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        [['image'], 'file'],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'Логин',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'image' => 'Изображение',
        'status' => 'Статус',
        'info' => 'Информация о себе'
    ];
}

public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
}


public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
}

public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
}

public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
{
    if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
        return null;
    }

    return static::findOne([
        'password_reset_token' => $token,
        'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
    ]);
}

public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
{
    if (empty($token)) {
        return false;
    }
    $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
    $parts = explode('_', $token);
    $timestamp = (int) end($parts);
    return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryKey();
}

public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key;
}

public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
}

public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
}

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}

public function generateAuthKey()
{
    $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
}

public function generatePasswordResetToken()
{
    $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
}

public function removePasswordResetToken()
{
    $this->password_reset_token = null;
}
```

**Controller action:**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['profile', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Standard ActiveForm with 1 field in View (can't paste it here properly for some reason, sorry). Do I need to add another files code? What can be the problem?

**UPD:** When I create new User, it is created with **empty fields** whether I write there something or not.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found out what was the problem.
Model edit:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        [['image'], 'file'],
        **[['username', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],**
    ];
}
```

Added this rule and managed to change the value :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);     

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if($model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['profile', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    } 
        return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```